# Is there a service to review prior flight plans?

Tags: flight-planning, flight-plans

I was wondering if there is anyone that offers on-line searching of prior flight plans.

Comment: Do you mean your own, or other's flight plans?

Comment: My own would be just fine.

Comment: [Lockheed Martic Flight Service](https://www.lmfsweb.afss.com/Website/home) has a function to see your own past filed flight plans, though I have no experience with it. I would presume that it would only show you flight plans you filed through LMFS.

Comment: I was looking for this function and was not able to find it a few days ago :(  If anyone knows how to get to it, this should provide everything I need as all of my plans are created and put through LM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lockheed Martin Flight Services (LMFS) provides a history of filed flight plans on their web site under **Flight Planning & Briefing | History**. The path to the particular page is: https://www.1800wxbrief.com/Website/showPilotHistory.

Unfortunately, only the last 15 days are available. So if your flight plan is older, it won't be displayed. Additionally, if you're filing your flight plans through a service provider that doesn't provide full LMFS integration (e.g., ForeFlight) it won't be displayed even if within 15 days. In this case, you'll need to refer to your service provider's interface.

Comment: Additionally, though this may not result in different data, LMSF offers a `Recent Flight Plans` drop down menu at the top left of the `Briefings, Flight Plans, & NavLogs` page, attempt at a direct link [here](https://www.lmfsweb.afss.com/Website/showFlightPlanForm).